# Is GeoExt styler extension available for GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, style

I've switched from my older version of GeoServer to GeoServer 2.3.3. In the older version, the  styler worked just fine, but I couldn’t find a styler extension that matched the new version. I tried with styler of 2.1.7 version in GeoServer, but it failed to work.

Can you tell me how to get a styler extension that works with the new version?

Comment: GeoServer 2.3.3 is so old there is no chance of an answer.